# Storing pointers in memcached

Tags: c, variables, pointers, casting, memcached

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way that I could technically store a pointer in memcached that I can later use. For example, I currently have code that is tracking information on users connected via sockets. Each user is tracked by a struct, containing the socket fd and the username. I'd like to be able to store the pointer of that struct in data in memcached so I can then lookup the user by name (key lookup) and retrieve the pointer to the struct associated with that user, then pass it to a function expecting a pointer. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing so? I'm struggling with type casting a bit and still learning C. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: It certainly should be possible (a pointer is just a number, after all), but considering that pointers are valid only in the process where they were created (barring cases like shared memory blocks where you could just use offsets) it seems odd to propose sending them off to some other process to be looked up later. Why not just keep the pointers in the process? Maybe you mean to put the actual struct in memcached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an appropriate application for memcached. Its purpose is to serve as a **shared** cache between multiple similar processes; since pointers are only valid within a single process, storing them in a shared location doesn't make sense.

If you want a key/value lookup, use an appropriate data structure (such as a hash table) within your application. You don't need memcached for this; it will be far slower than doing the lookup locally.